# biblatex - citing dead author

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to put

```
author={{\textdagger}Last, First},
```

in some bibtex entries, and have `biblatex` treat it exactly as some existing

```
author={Last, First},
```

entries (i.e. sorted as if the dagger was not there, treated as identical to Last for dashing etc.).

Is this possible?

Comment: In `biblatex`, that's what `sortname` is for.  `author = {Author, Adam}, sortname = {Smith, John},` sorts under 'Smith, John'.  You can even override that if you like by adding a `sortkey = {ZZZZZ}`, which would sort it under 'ZZZZZ'.  And you can also override *that* by adding a `presort` field...

Comment: Thanks for that; it does make the sort order right, but it does not treat Last the same as †Last in citations in the text, because it thinks "†Last, First" is a different author from "Last, First" and so requires disambiguating (i.e. I get "F. Last (2014)" when "Last (2014)" would already be unambiguous).

Comment: Wouldn't they be different authors?  Either someone is dead or alive...

Comment: Normal practice is to cite people exactly as in the source document.   So if some articles have Last and some more recent ones have †Last, I should keep the † in some of my citations, but in all other respects treat the two cases as the same person.

Comment: @jon - Maybe we're discovering an author category called a "Schrödinger's Author" -- neither dead nor alive until his/her name is written out to a bibliography...

Comment: @Mico -- Haha.  touché!

Comment: I would look at the `nosort` option of biber which is designed for this. See the PDF biber manual as this option has to be set in the biber config file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an alternative, which enables you to use an option `dead` to mark that an author has died. It then adds the dagger on the first occurrence of the author's name. This may allow more "logical" markup of the `.bib` database.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{living,
  author = {Last, Alpha},
  title = {I'm Alive},
  date = {2014}
}
@book{dead,
  author = {Last, First},
  title = {Dead},
  options = {dead},
  date = {2014},
}
@book{dead2,
  author = {Last, First},
  title = {Still Dead},
  options = {dead},
  date = {2014}
}
@book{notalive,
  author = {Last, Last},
  title = {Not Alive},
  options = {dead},
  date = {2014}
}
@book{alive:not,
  author = {Last, Last},
  title = {Not Alive},
  options = {dead},
  date = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newtoggle{riptoggle}
\DeclareEntryOption{dead}[true]{\settoggle{riptoggle}{#1}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
        {}
        {\iftoggle{riptoggle}
           {\textdagger}
           {}}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - I might be able to use something like this, but please remember that the problem is not to add † to every article published after the author has died, but to cite articles correctly.  It should be cited with † iff it's published with †.

Comment: @KeithB Are you okay with the output though if `dashed=false` is activated?