# How can I add a field to an existing biblatex type?

Tags: biblatex

I wish to add a new entry to the [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) bibliography type `@online`. For example,

```
@online{abc,
  author   = {A Author},
  title    = {Some lengthy title that's awesome},
  url      = {http://tex.stackexchange.com},
  breakurl = {}
}
```

I've added a `breakurl` field (that could be blank), that I want to condition on when using the `online` bibliography driver to possibly insert a line break. However, I'm unable to successfully achieve this, even after following the guidelines in [Add field "tome" to biblatex entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/5764).

Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents,showframe}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@online{abc,
  author   = {A Author},
  title    = {Some lengthy title that's awesome},
  url      = {http://tex.stackexchange.com},
  breakurl = {}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/5764
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim,nullok=true]{breakurl}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{breakurl}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{breakurl}{}% Used as a boolean variable

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

After compiling with `biber`, the `breakurl` field is not visible in the `.bbl`:

```
\refsection{0}
  \sortlist{nty}{nty}
    \entry{abc}{online}{}
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{hash=1318a946c3fffa54cec1130748f21c17}{Author}{A\bibinitperiod}{A}{A\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{1318a946c3fffa54cec1130748f21c17}
      \strng{fullhash}{1318a946c3fffa54cec1130748f21c17}
      \field{sortinit}{A}
      \field{sortinithash}{b685c7856330eaee22789815b49de9bb}
      \field{labelnamesource}{author}
      \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
      \field{title}{Some lengthy title that's awesome}
      \verb{url}
      \verb http://tex.stackexchange.com
      \endverb
    \endentry
  \endsortlist
\endrefsection
```

The motivation behind adding a new field is that it can easily be ignored by `biber` or by the driver. An alternative would be to include such line breaks as part of the field entries in the `@online` source, but that is not acceptable.

The more general question would be: How can I add a field to an existing `biblatex` type?

Comment: In short: the data model commands should be put in a `.dbx` file that you then load in the options: `\usepackage[datamodel=mydbxfile]{biblatex}`. I'd probably also do: `\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[online]{breakurl}` since this seems like a fairly specific use.

Comment: Can you pass the information to biber via another (existing) field, i.e. define `\breakurl` which expands to nothing when you are not using it?

Comment: Related [Data model macro cannot be used in preamble](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238554/35864).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to [Add field “tome” to biblatex entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864) was written back in the good old days when datamodel commands were still allowed in the document preamble, starting from [version 2.9](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/05b47b2c8ace6460604c34ef9c0146264e34a846) those commands cannot be used in the preamble in order to avoid complications and unwanted behaviour. The answer has now been amended to reflect this change.

So if you want to use datamodel commands now you will have to use a datamodel file (either a `.dbx` or `biblatex-dm.cfg`).
You could call this file `werner.dbx`, its content would be

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim,nullok=true]{breakurl}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{breakurl}
```

You would then have to load `biblatex` with the option `datamodel=werner`.

Please note that `nullok=true` does not ensure that the field appears in the `.bbl` even if it is empty, it just doesn't generate a warning. So `breakurl = {},` does not make the field `breakurl` appear in the `.bbl`.

---

You seem to want to use the `breakurl` field as a boolean value. This can be done slightly easier with `\DeclareEntryOption`.

```
\newtoggle{blx@breakurl}
\DeclareEntryOption{breakurl}[true]{%
  \settoggle{blx@breakurl}{#1}%
  % or whatever you need to do here
}
```

Defines a new option `breakurl` that sets a toggle.

In your `.bib` entry you then have

```
options  = {breakurl},
```

to toggle `breakurl` on.

You can have a look at [biblatex - citing dead author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163646/35864), [How to remove comma from authoryear citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/271915/35864), [Functionality of apacites \nocitemeta with biblatex-apa: adding asterisks to author lastnames (meta-analysis)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156706/35864) and [Change 'Chapter' in @inbook to 'Appendix' for one BibLaTex entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179535/35864) for more examples and uses of `\DeclareEntryOption`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{abc,
  author   = {A Author},
  title    = {Some lengthy title that's awesome},
  url      = {http://tex.stackexchange.com},
  options  = {breakurl},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newtoggle{blx@breakurl}
\togglefalse{blx@breakurl}
\DeclareEntryOption{breakurl}[true]{%
  \settoggle{blx@breakurl}{#1}%
  % or whatever you need to do here
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

According  to the biblatex manual (`texdoc biblatex`)

> It is not possible to add to a loaded data model by using the macros below in your preamble as the preamble is read after Biblatex has defined critical internal macros based on the data model. If any data model macro is used in a document, it will be ignored and a warning will be generated.

The command to declare data model (and thus new field) should be in configuration files.

To insert them in a document one can use `filecontents` environment to generate the configuration file.

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim,nullok=true]{breakurl}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{breakurl}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{breakurl}{}% Used as a boolean variable
\end{filecontents}
```