# Customizing biblatex+biber to obtain THESISNAME and bibliographic dash

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib, biber

I have discovered `biblatex` and `biber` just a few months ago, they are fabulous resources but unfortunately I haven't found *yet* a resource explaining how to customize them.

I'm using `natbib` syntax, and would like to change two things:

1. whenever I am in a `phdthesis` entry, `biblatex-natbib` will output the string “Doctoral dissertation” in the reference, but in fact in France (and more generally in Europe) we have many kinds of PhD: thèse de doctorat, thèse de 3e cycle, thèse d'état, HDR, habilitation, etc. In the BST styles I use for the French Mathematical Society there is a field called `THESISNAME` where I can specify the type of PhD and this string will replace the default “PhD Thesis,” how can I introduce such an entry in `biblatex-natbib`?
2. when there are many entries by the same author I would like the 2nd to n-th entries to start by a long dash instead of the author's name. How can this be obtained?

[I realize that it wouldn't be reasonable to ask a question on tex.stackexchange every time some small customization is needed, but I'm convinced that if somebody can show me how to do those two small changes, I will understand how the system works and will be able to make other similar changes by myself.]

Comment: For the first question, it cannot be solved in preamble: you have to define a new `data model` in a  `.dbx` file. See Moewe's explanations in his answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286987/how-can-i-add-a-field-to-an-existing-biblatex-type).For the second question, you don't say which style you use, but, for instance, `authoryear-comp`will do that.

Comment: I use natbib, is that what you mean by "style"?

Comment: `biblatex`'s generic `@thesis` type has a field called `type` that would be pretty much equivalent to your `thesisname`. The field can be used with bibstrings, so you can easy set up predefined strings (see e.g. https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/660) or you can use it as a free-form field.

Comment: No, the natbib option is a compatibility module. Bibstyle is, for instance, auhoryear, authortitle, numeric. You can see a list in § 3.3, Standard Styles, pp.72–78 in the documentation.

Comment: I use the following command in my document: `\usepackage[natbib=true,style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}` but `apa`is not mentioned in §3.3 and the document biblatex.pdf has no index so that I can search for it. Is `authoryear-comp`orthogonal to `apa`, if yes how do I set this option?

Comment: `style=apa` is a contributed style and not one of the core `biblatex` styles ([`biblatex-apa`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa)), so it is not documented in the  `biblatex` manual, but in its own documentation. If you plan on writing your own style, I recommend you do not base it on `biblatex-apa`. `biblatex-apa` was specifically written to implement the complex rules of the APA as far as possible with `biblatex`, the style is less customisable than the standard styles since it is a single-purpose style.

Comment: A first resource for simple `biblatex` customisations is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864. But there is no comprehensive tutorial for more complex things. You can find a lot of questions and answers on this site, though, so if you search for specific issues chances are you can find something and if not, you can ask a question and you will probably get a usable answer.

Comment: @Bernard Do you think you can collect your comments here into an answer, so the question can be marked as resolved?

Comment: @moewe: Yes, I'll do it in a moment, as it might be useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, it cannot be solved in preamble: you have to define a new data model in a .dbx file. See Moewe's explanations in his answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286987/how-can-i-add-a-field-to-an-existing-biblatex-type).

For the second question, the [`authoryear-comp` style](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/52-style-authoryear-comp-biber.pdf) will do that. You can see a list of  the core `biblatex` styles in § 3.3, Standard Styles, pp. 72–78 in [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), and these styles can be further customised – the `xpatch` package can be quite helpful for this job.

Comment: For point one it may be helpful to mention that the  existing `type` field is essentially what yannis had in mind with `THESISNAME`, so it might just be a matter of switching to the predefine field. Since the question asks about general resources, it may be worth mentioning the standard https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864 (of course it doesn't nearly cover everything that `biblatex` can do, but it is a start) not only in the comments, but also in the answer.